# Typesetting URL/URI/IRI in plain TeX

Tags: urls, plain-tex

I would like to be able to allow line breaking on `/`'s, `?`, and `&`'s.

I understand I should change the `\catcode`'s of those letters, but I don't want them to be global, but instead restricted to inside of the macro. This is what I have tried:

```
\def\url{%
  \begingroup%
    \def\urlaux##1{##1\endgroup}%
    \catcode`\&=13
    \def&{\penalty0\char`\&}%
    \urlaux}

\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/some/long/path/and?someBizarreLong=param&andYetAnotherSuchBizarreLong=param}
\bye
```

but TeX tells me that `&` is inaccessible on its `\def`inition

I remember reading something like: “*The catcode change is not being done during the execution of the macro, but during reading of it*”, or something along those lines.

But I have tried moving the definition of the ampersand to inside of the `\urlaux`, for example, without success.

How could I make it accessible?

Comment: You need to alter the catcode when _making_ the definition: here you've tokenized `\url` with `&` as the tab alignment char.

Comment: @Joseph: Yes, I've read that *exact same* sentence now a quadzillion times, yet I gain no insight from it as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TeX assigns category code when an argument is grabbed and tokenized. As a result, inside your definition of `\url`, `&` has catcode 'tab alignment' (assuming normal rules apply). You can only `\def` an active char, so this step fails as you've observed.

What you need to do is make sure that the definition of `\url` contains an active `&`:

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\&=\active
\gdef\url{%
  \begingroup%
    \def\urlaux##1{##1\endgroup}%
    \catcode`\&=\active
    % Catcode of & that is important here is when \url is defined:
    \def&{\penalty0\char`\&}% 
    \urlaux}
\endgroup

\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/some/long/path/and?someBizarreLong=param&andYetAnotherSuchBizarreLong=param}
\bye
```

Notice that you still need to alter the catcode of `&` when grabbing the *argument* of `\urlaux` too! (The entire 'trick' here depends on not grabbing the argument using `\url` as that will tokenize at the wrong time.) That means that reordering to say

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\&=\active
\gdef\url{%
  \begingroup%
    % Catcode of & that is important here is when \url is defined:
    \def&{\penalty0\char`\&}% 
    \def\urlaux##1{##1\endgroup}%
    \catcode`\&=\active
    \urlaux}
\endgroup
```

will also work: the second catcode change is about the grabbed argument and has nothing to do with the definition of `&` that we are using.

Comment: Thanks! Though, am I right in arguing that `\url` has *no argument*?

Comment: @morbusg Yes, I'll clarify

Answer (score 7):

It is much better *not* to change catcodes mid document but instead change the mathcode (as then it works as much as possibe even in macro arguments) this is what url.sty does

url.sty uses hardly any latex so works with plain tex with a bit of encouragement, or you could simply edit the file to remove the latex bits rather than defining stubs as here

[image]

```
\catcode`\@=11
\def\@namedef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\@ifundefined#1#2#3{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax
#2\else#3\fi}
\let\protect\relax
\let\ProcessOptions\relax
\def\DeclareOption#1#2{}
\def\@makeother#1{\catcode`#1=12 }
\def\@ifnextchar#1#2#3{#2}
\def\@empty{}
\def\@firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\def\@secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\newcount\@tempcnta
\input url.sty
\def\UrlFont{\tt}

\hrule

abc abc \url{http://www.example.com/one/two/three.html}  abc
abc abc \url{http://www.example.com/one/two/three.html}  abc
abc abc \url{http://www.example.com/one/two/three.html}  abc
abc abc \url{http://www.example.com/one/two/three.html}  abc
abc abc \url{http://www.example.com/one/two/three.html}  abc

\bye
```

Comment: Thanks. How does `\mathcode` come into play?

Comment: Donald's trick in url.sty is to make characters by mathcode"8000 (same as `'`) which means then you can access their active definition _without_ making them active. furthermore linebreaking is allowed with two differemt strengths eg at `/` and at `.` by making characters be \mathrel or \mathbin then the whole URL is set in inline math mode

Answer (score 7):

Use `eplain`:

```
\input eplain
\beginpackages
\usepackage{url}
\endpackages

\rightskip=10em minus 8em % avoid overfull box
\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/some/long/path/and?someBizarreLong=param&andYetAnotherSuchBizarreLong=param}

\bye
```

[image]

Your (simplistic) definition can be corrected with

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\&=\active % we want an active & in the replacement text of \url

\gdef\url{% \gdef because we're in a group
  \begingroup
  \def\urlaux##1{##1\endgroup}%
  \catcode`\&=\active
  \def&{\penalty0\char`\&}%
  \urlaux}
\endgroup

\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/some/long/path/and?someBizarreLong=param&andYetAnotherSuchBizarreLong=param}
\bye
```

Comment: I did try using `url.sty` via eplain, but I couldn't get it to work (I guess my other definitions somehow break it). But I didn't really need all the bling bling of the package, so I thought I'd just keep it really simple. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 3):

The opmac package (intended for plainTeX) implements `\url` too:

```
\input opmac

\rightskip=0pt plus5em
\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/some/long/path/and?someBizarreLong=param&andYetAnotherSuchBizarreLong=param}

\end
```

Of course, you needn't use whole `opmac.tex` but you can be inspired by the macro `\url` from it where you can see:

```
\def\url#1{{\def\tmpb{#1}%
   \replacestrings{//}{{\urlskip\urlslashslash\urlbskip}}%
   \replacestrings{/}{{\urlskip/\urlbskip}}%
   \replacestrings{.}{{\urlskip.\urlbskip}}%
   \replacestrings{?}{{\urlskip?\urlbskip}}%
   \replacestrings{=}{{\urlskip=\urlbskip}}%
   \replacestrings{~}{{\char`\~}}%
   \replacestrings{_}{{\char`\_}}%
   \replacestrings{^}{{\char`\^}}%
   \replacestrings{\\}{\bslash}%
   \replacestrings{\{}{{\char`\{}}%
   \replacestrings{\}}{{\char`\}}}%
   \replacestrings{&}{{\urlbskip\char`\& \urlskip}}%
   \def\|{}\ulink[#1]{\urlfont\tmpb}%
}}
```

It means that the `\url` is implemetned by `\replacestrings` which is better than catcode changing because catcode changing does not work when whole `\url{...}` is a part of a parameter of another macro.

If you decided to do catcode manipulating then you can use `\adef` macro which is stolen from `opmac.tex` too:

```
\def\adef#1{\catcode`#1=13 \bgroup \lccode`\~=`#1\lowercase{\egroup\def~}}

\def\url{%
   \begingroup%
   \adef&{\penalty0\char`\&}% 
   \def\urlaux##1{##1\endgroup}%
   \urlaux}
```

You can see that the catcode setting is more simple.

Answer (score 3):

Package [`url`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) can also be used with plain TeX via the help of [`miniltx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/miniltx):

```
\input miniltx.tex
\input url.sty
\resetatcatcode

\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177340/typesetting-url-uri-iri-in-plain-tex}

\bye
```

> [image: Result]